# How to delete pods from subversion branch in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, svn, branch, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods to manage third party libraries and now I need to remove one of the pods. 
Normally I would go to the local folder where I have checked out the repository folder to delete the files and then run pod install.
However, when trying to find the local folder for the subversion branch, I can not seem to find it. I checked in Xcode 5+ and it says the local folder for my branch is the same as the one I branched from. This seems strange to me because of how subversion normally works.

It would seem counterintuitive to be forced to check out every branch manually to be able to interact with the files from the command line.

How do I go about resolving this and deleting a pod from my branch without messing up the source of the branch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you're saying that subversion makes this more difficult but to remove a pod from a project you should remove the line from your `Podfile` and run `pod install`

Comment: Yes, well this is how do it normally. But now I need to branch my project and remove a pod only from the branch and not the trunk. And herein lies the problem, how do I remove a pod only from a fresh branch without removing the file from the trunk? To be able to use a subversion repository you need to check it out and then you have a folder to work in. But how about when you branch it? Where do I find the folder to work with? I would be surprised if I need to check out the branch by itself and then work on it, but maybe this is the only way?